# Dagger AppComponent unresolved error android

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I created new project with android **x** .I followed every instruction to add dagger in my project.

applied plugin

**apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'**

**Here are my Dagger dependencies**

Dagger

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger"
kapt  "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
kapt  "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger"
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

**App Di class**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
modules = arrayOf(
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class
    , AppModule::class,
    ViewModelBuilder::class,
    NetworkModule::class
)
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<AppSingleton> {

@Component.Builder
abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<AppSingleton>()
}
@Module
class AppModule {

@Provides
fun context(app: AppSingleton): Context = app.applicationContext

@Singleton
@Provides
fun preferences(app: AppSingleton): SharedPreferences {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app)
}
}
```

I tried to rebuild the app . Tried many solution but not resolving error .

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Fred DaggerAppComponent unresolved

Comment: That's just because it wasn't generated by the annotation processor. This can be because you didn't add it, or you didn't run it, it even because you have another error related with the dependency framework. Can you post the error output?

Comment: Sometimes the compiler doesn't generate de DaggerAppComponent because of an error, you need to check the Error log to figure out where's the problem.